# TimeoutException in WCF after multiple calls

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, timeout, duplex-channel

Maybe I am implementing WCF improperly, but I seem to be getting a WCF exception while using `NetNamedPipedBindings` after making numerous calls.

Here is the high level of what I am doing. Basically, I am working on an out of proc exe and using WCF named pipes to communicate back and forth. I leave my host open via this attribute:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

Then, in my client I create a `static DuplexChannelFactory` that I instantiate once and then use as needed via:

```
channelFactory.CreateChannel().MakeCall();
```

I have added a Ping method just to make sure that the host is working properly (since the host will send events back that we do not want to miss without knowing). This Ping method runs once every 5 seconds and simply returns a true. However, after running for a couple of minutes I get a `TimeoutException`. Here is my exception trace:

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel
>   channel, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

I have opened JustDecompile and see that this error is most likely happening here:

```
connection = this.connectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(timeout)
```

However, I do not see any reason why this would timeout after working for a couple of pings previously? What setting do I need to set to make this infinite and/or is there another way for me to implement this WCF event server (it is used for on-demand processing too) from the client or server side?

**UPDATE**

I make about 6 pings before I start to see the call attempt and no return.

Comment: _I do not see any reason why this would timeout after working for a couple of minutes previously?_ - that makes a lot of sense actually and marks it as a resource leak. You're not closing/disposing something.

Comment: @HenkHolterman OK, but what is it something on the server or client? Should I not call CreateChannel multiple times? Maybe CreateChannel and use that over and over? My guess would be that it is somewhere on the client, because I can keep the server up, kill the client and it will work for a little upon client restart.

Comment: Hmm, 6 pings is half a minute, not a couple of minutes.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with duplex channels but I would say keep-open or Dispose after each use. The presence of a pool suggests the latter, with a `using(){}` pattern.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I will give it a shot, and will update my question. It is a couple of minutes until I get the first exception, the multithreaded timer threw me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you cannot call `CreateChannel` over and over it appears. There is no dispose method as this is just a proxy of my WCF interface. So, I just solved this by storing the reference to the proxy and recreating it if the host needed re-instantiated.

You would think there would be some sort of documentation about this. It especially does not help when there are blogs that are written where they do call CreateChannel multiple times.

UPDATE:

[Here is what I found as to how this should be solved...although it did not work for me.., but seems to for others](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2008/05/23/clean-up-wcf-clients--the-right-way.aspx)

Snipped code in case the link dies:

You have to use a using that casts to IClientChannel, and then reset your reference inside the using. The channel will close properly, but your reference will remain open. Notice the casts

```
using (IClientChannel client = (IClientChannel)channelFactory.CreateChannel())
{
    var proxy = (IMyInterface)client;
}
```

Comment: You can cast the channel reference to IClientChannel, or directly to IDisposable. And then just use using.

Comment: I will have to try that, but if I do that will I be able to use my classes methods?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PipeList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd581625) from sysinternals to see if you keep creating new pipes unnecessarily. They will show up as GUIDs. See [MSDN blogs for further reference on WCF named pipe naming conventions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2011/03/22/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name.aspx).